# Use of shadows on different backgrounds

Tags: colours, light

I have a UI element composed of two sub-elements, one magenta and one white. When a shadow is applied to the super element, it is a lot more pronounced / contrasted when seen alongside the lighter, white element than the magenta.

My question is, to what extent is this a realistic representation of how shadow behaves in real life, and secondly, does it justify setting up two separate shadows and reducing opacity/radius around the white element?

[image]

EDIT:

Here's a close up, with greys moving from #D3D5D4 to #D1D0D1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: IT IS RENDERING JUST FINE.

I took another look at this on my PC instead of my phone, and it works just fine. I think it looks weird in your zoomed example because it has been interpolated there. When I zoom in on a screenshot of it, it looks like this:

[image]

Original answer below:

This shouldn't happen.

What I think is happining is that the white element is getting two shadows. This could be because it's a nested object and it inherits a shadow which is then overlayed over the encompassing purple elements's shadow. Or it could be for an entirely different reason.

At any rate, this looks like a bug, not a spec/design choice.

Comment: There's only a single shadow attribute applied to the underlying view, the magenta and white are shadowless, if you like. I'm leaning towards it being a bug as well, having looked at the greys close up.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Google's documentation of Material Design (https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#), there is a piece about shadows and how they developed the shadow patterns they use. It has to do with elevation, as far as realism goes. That link above is a great resource, so definitely check it out!

As far the design aspect (again, documented in the link above), shadows create a layered (z-index) perception. Like buttons for example, shadows usually indicate that an element is interactive.

Answer (score 1):

First i suggest you to investigate some basics regarding to light/shadow:
[Smashingmag. Trick to bring light and shadow into your design](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/5-simple-tricks-to-bring-light-and-shadow-into-your-designs/)

The major headache in the above task with the so toned purlpe is the state of the color, its the tipical case when the amount of light and tone will trick your eyes that you think you will have to give more shadow. If the purple is darker you will rise the amount of the dark and vice versa. If you plan this to web, i dont think you have to wory about to give darker shade to a color like this, otherwise you will chase your tail forewer.

The above mentioned materialdesign is also a great article i suggest you to read, they worked this out by a lot of prestudies with a lot of great minds.

Its more important what inside, the content. If you can make the container content's as eyecatching, no one will take care of about the visual hierarchy caused eyetrick that this kind of color and card shadow could cause.

And of course the surrounding elements are also important.

What is the aim? To eyecatch with the purple, then to lead the user to interact with the card's footer? Give some questions what you would like to reach.

Here is some article about cards: [UXDesign](https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-cards-c0d12ab581c4)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The aim is just to display some basic data in the box, for a smartphone app. I'll take a look at the material design docs.